# How to pre-configure and prefill official MySQL docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I want to build a new MySQL image based on the official MySQL docker container image. I want to reduce the number of parameters I need to add when running the image. (eg. `-e MYSQL_USER`, `-e MYSQL_DATABASE` and even `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='rootsecret'`)
 that already includes my settings for the global variables and my Create Database SQL file in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder.

How do I add all my settings and create a new image to simply `docker run mysql:config1` `docker run mysql:config2` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has to be written into the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mysql:latest
LABEL Name=mylabel Version=0.0.1
COPY path/to/sh/sql/sql.gz/files /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='rootpassword'
```

As stated in the documentation on the official docker website:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order.

Answer (score 1):

You could build your own mysql docker image using a docker file, configure username, password and everything else you might need, build that image, upload it to the docker hub and then when you launch a new docker container you just use the previously built container.

An example of a Docker file to build an ubuntu image with a mysql server inside would be something like bellow (save it to a file called Dockerfile):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
    RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \                                           
    && { \
        echo debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/data-dir \
            select ''; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass \
            password 'Desired-Password'; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass \
            password 'Desired-Password'; \
        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/remove-test-db \
            select true; \
    } | debconf-set-selections \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client
```

Then build your mysql docker container like this (you have to be in the folder where the Docker file was/is saved):

```
docker build my-ubuntu-mysql-docker
```

Then you have to push it to the docker hub and then you can use it to start a new docker container like this:

```
docker run -d -p 2222:22 -p 3306:3306 --name my-ubuntu-mysql-docker ...
```

Where 2222 is local ssh port mapped to ssh port 22 of the docker container and 3306 is local mysql port mapped to the mysql port of the docker container.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you you would want to do is to modify Mysql's image [entry point](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/86431f073b3d2f963d21e33cb8943f0bdcdf143d/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh)
and please note that you do not need to pass all the parameters, most of them are optional